# Chromium build fails after a while on Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I am getting a build error after a while, and I am unsure as to why.
Any ideas or hints?

[image: Build error]

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the
libc6:i386
package, which contains
/lib/ld-linux.so.2
needed to load shared libraries.
Without this, it prevented me from running various shared libraries, and merely said "no such file or directory" which is a crap error message imho since the file is clearly there, just not executable.